# Azure - Logging Request Details to EventHub from API Management

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-api-management

The basic example provided by Microsoft when I add the Log to EventHub action to my Incoming processing is useful but I want to be able to log the Request Content and Content Length. Currently I cannot find any documentation or definitions of the context or context.Request objects used in this example.

```
<log-to-eventhub logger-id ='logger-id'>
  @( string.Join(",", DateTime.UtcNow, context.Deployment.ServiceName, context.RequestId, context.Request.IpAddress, context.Operation.Name))
</log-to-eventhub>
```

Can someone please point me to the documentation for this, or at least tell me how to get the content of the request body or the body length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can get the body:

```
string inBody = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
```

For more information, see the `context`, `context.Request` and `IMessage` sections in the [Context variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables) table.